# Nested groups using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

Lets say I have an object with the following properties.

```
    public string VendorNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartDivision { get; set; }
```

I have a list of about 300 of these objects. I am trying to group them first by VendorNumber, then by Division. I should be able to drill into them like so afterwards:

1. Vendor A
   Divsion 1
   --Part 0001
   --Part 0002
   --Part 0003
   Divsiion 2
   --Part 0001
2. Vendor B
   Division 1
   --Part 0023
   ...etc...

I can do the first grouping easily like so:

```
var vendorGroups =
    from v in vendors
    group v by v.VendorNumber into vg
    select new { VendorNumber = vg.Key, Parts = vg, Count = vg.Count() };
```

I can't seem to get the nested grouping working though even after referring to some other posts here and on the MSDN. Thanks.

---

Here is what I ended up with from the suggestions:

I have made some progress using suggestions but I can't seem to access the second level when looping:

```
var vendorGroups = forecastHelpers
    .GroupBy(x => new { VendorNumber = x.VendorNumber, Division = x.PartDivision, Level = 1 })
    .GroupBy(x => new { VendorNumber = x.Key.VendorNumber }).OrderBy(x => x.Key.VendorNumber);

    foreach (var vendorGroup in vendorGroups)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VendorNumber: " + vendorGroup.Key.VendorNumber);
    foreach (var divisionGroup in vendorGroup)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("     Division: " + divisionGroup.Key.Division);
        foreach (var partNumber in divisionGroup)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("          PartNumber: " + partNumber.PartNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update 2: 
This could also be written like so:

```
var vendorGroupings = from f in forecastHelpers
                        group f by new { VendorNumber = f.VendorNumber, Division = f.PartDivision, Level = 2 } into vendorGroups
                        from divisionGroups in
                            (from division in vendorGroups
                            orderby division.PartDivision
                            group division by new { Division = division.PartDivision }) 
                        orderby vendorGroups.Key.VendorNumber
                        group divisionGroups by new { VendorNumber = vendorGroups.Key.VendorNumber, Level = 1 };


foreach (var vendorGroup in vendorGroupings)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VendorNumber: " + vendorGroup.Key.VendorNumber);

    foreach (var division in vendorGroup)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("     Division: " + division.Key.Division);

        foreach (var part in division)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("          PartNumber: " + part.PartNumber);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the PartDivision values unique to each vendor, or could the same value be used by two different vendors?

Comment: Please look at the SO Link below,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578887/nested-group-by-linq][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578887/nested-group-by-linq

Comment: PartDivision values are NOT unique to each vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var vendorGroups = vendors.GroupBy(x => new { x.VendorNumber, x.PartDivision})
                          .GroupBy(x => x.Key.VendorNumber);
```

To access the second level, you need to do `x.Key.PartDivision`, not just `x.Key` (which works for the top level).

---

To address your edit:

```
var vendorGroups = forecastHelpers
    .GroupBy(x => new { VendorNumber = x.VendorNumber, Division = x.PartDivision, Level = 1 })
    .GroupBy(x => new { VendorNumber = x.Key.VendorNumber }).OrderBy(x => x.Key.VendorNumber);

foreach (var vendorGroup in vendorGroups)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VendorNumber: " + vendorGroup.Key.VendorNumber);  

    foreach(var division in vendorGroup)
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Division: " + division.Key.division); 
       foreach (var part in division)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Part: " + part.PartNumber); 
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to access the second level... Please see my updated post.

Comment: Nevermind I'm an idiot. I've updated the post to show looping. Thanks.

Comment: @BBauer42 - Edited to show the nested loops.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var grouped = from v in vendors
              group v by new { VN = v.VendorNumber, VD = v.PartDivision} into grp
              orderby grp.Key.VN, grp.Key.VD
              select new {VN_VD=grp.Key, Items=grp};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vendorGroups =
    from v in vendors
    group v by v.VendorNumber into vg
    select new { VendorNumber = vg.Key, Parts = vg, Count = vg.Count() };
foreach (var vg in vendorGroups)
{
    var vendor = vg.VendorNumber;
    foreach (var divGroup in vg.Parts.GroupBy(x => x.PartDivision))
    {
        var division = divGroup.Key;
        foreach (var part in divGroup)
        {
            // do stuff with vendor, division, and part
        }
    }
}
```

It could probably be done with purely query syntax, but I find it clear and simple as-is.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from x in set
            group x by x.VendorNumber into g
            select new 
            {
                VendorNumber = g.Key
                GroupedBy = g.ToLookup(x => x.PartDivision)                                 
            };

foreach(var x in query)
{
   var venderNumber = x.VendorNumber;
   foreach(var y in x.GroupBy)
   {
       var partDivision = y.Key
       foreach(Vendor item in y)
       {
           //do stuff with vendor
       }
   }
}
```